# Why is my else conditional returning expression result unused [-Werror,-Wunused-value]?

Tags: c, if-statement, char, cs50

I am creating a program that takes a 26-alpha character key as a key to cipher plain text.

I am busy creating a function that is responsible for the cipher.

they key i am currently using: qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm

for conext (my function):

my function only takes one char, at a time, from the plaintext to be cipher

```
char ciphertext(char plainchar,string key)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = plainchar;
    char cipher;
    if (isupper(plainchar)) 
    {
        int c = b - 65; //convert char to its alphabetical position

        cipher = key[c]; // asign the alphabetical position to its key position equivalent
        if (islower(cipher))
        {
            cipher = toupper(cipher);
        }

        return cipher;
    }

    else if (islower(plainchar))
    {
            int c = b - 97;

            cipher = key[c];
            if (isupper(cipher))
            {
                cipher = tolower(cipher);
            }
    }

    else if (isdigit(plainchar))
    {
            cipher = plainchar;
    }

    else  (plainchar == ' ' || plainchar == ',' || plainchar == '!' );
    {
        cipher = plainchar;
    }

    return cipher;

}
```

the last condition `else  (plainchar == ' ' || plainchar == ',' || plainchar == '!' );` is giving me the problem.

This is the error:

```
substitution.c:104:49: error: expression result unused [-Werror,-Wunused-value]
    else  (plainchar == ' ' || plainchar == ',' || plainchar == '!' );
```

the terminal points to the `||` as the probelm and I don't know why. I've done this before and it worked just fine.

**PS my debugger keeps crashing and preventing me from debugging this**

Answer (score 2):

Instead of else

```
else  (plainchar == ' ' || plainchar == ',' || plainchar == '!' );
```

you have to use else if

```
else  if (plainchar == ' ' || plainchar == ',' || plainchar == '!' );
```

Pay attention to the semicolon after the else (or else if). It seems it is a typo. Remove it.

As you change only alpha characters then in fact this part of the code

```
else if (isdigit(plainchar))
{
        cipher = plainchar;
}

else if (plainchar == ' ' || plainchar == ',' || plainchar == '!' )
{
    cipher = plainchar;
}
```

could be changed just like

```
else
{
    cipher = plainchar;
}
```

In the function `is_valid_key` this for loop

```
int is_valid_key(string verify)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < verify[i]; i++)
    //...
```

is incorrect. It seems you mean

```
int is_valid_key(string verify)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; verify[i] != '\0'; i++)
    //...
```

Comment: when I did that, I got further errors ( I updated my Q to reflect this)

Comment: @Sizwe I am sorry but we are not here to update your program removing all compiler errors. You asked a question and I answered it. If you have other problems that ask new questions.

Comment: I understand. But no worries. I figured it it out. Your answer helped